# Unknown Syntax Error's

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import random

# Game Function
def game():

print ("Welcome to the cavern of secrets!")

time.sleep(3)

print("You enter a dark cavern out of curiosity. It is dark and you can't see much. You notice a sword on the ground.")
part1 = input("which do you take The Sword or not?.")

# sword taken

if part1 == "Sword" or part1 == "sword":
    print ("You have taken the sword")
    sword = 1

# sword not taken

if part1 == "not" or part1 == "no":
    print ("You have taken nopthing")
    sword = 0

time.sleep(3)
print ("You've come to a crosspath, in the distance to the left there is a small glowing object, the right just looks dark.")
part2 = input("Which way do you wish to go, Left or Right?")

# left

if part2 == "Left" or part2 == "left":
    print ("you have gone left")
    time.sleep(5)
    print ("You approach the object......")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("As you get closer to the object you notice that the glowing object is actually an eye!!!!!!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("you look below the eye and see 2 fangs. TYou now see that the3 glowing object and the fangs are actually a spider.")
    part3 = input("Do you try to fight it, Yes or No?")

# fight spider

if part3 == "yes" or part3 == "Yes":

    # With sword

    if sword == 1:
        print("You have a sword to fight the spider with!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You quickly jab the spider in the eye to take the advantage!")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("FIGHTING.............")
        print ("YOU MUST HIT ABOVE A FIVE TO KILL THE SPIDER!!!!!!")
        print(" IF THE SPIDER HITS HIGHER THAN YOU, YOU WILL DIE!!!!!!!!")
        time.sleep(5)
        mydmg = int(random.randint(3, 10))
        spiderdmg = int(random.randint(1, 6))
        print ("You hit a", mydmg)
        time.sleep(2)
        print("The spider hit a", spiderdmg)

        if spiderdmg > mydmg:
            print ("The spider has dealt more damage than you!!!! You DIE!!!!!")
            complete = 1
            return complete

        elif mydmg < 5:
            print ("You didn't manage to kill the spider but you did manage to escape!!!")
            complete = 1
            return complete

   # Without Sword

else:
       print ("You don't have anything to fight with!!")
       time.sleep(2)
       print("FIGHTING.............")
       print ("YOU MUST HIT ABOVE A FIVE TO KILL THE SPIDER!!!!!!")
       print(" IF THE SPIDER HITS HIGHER THAN YOU, YOU WILL DIE!!!!!!!!")
       time.sleep(5)
       mydmg = int(random.randint(3, 7))
       spiderdmg = int(random.randint(1, 6))
       print("You hit a", mydmg)
       time.sleep(2)
       print ("The spider hits a", spiderdmg)
       time.sleep(2)

       if spiderdmg > mydmg:
           print ("The spider has dealt more damage than you!!!! You DIE!!!!!")
           complete = 0
           return complete

       elif mydmg < 5:
           print ("You didn't manage to kill the spider but you did manage to escape!!!")
           complete = 1
           return complete


    # DONT FIGHT SPIDER

       elif mydmg:
                print("You try to leave the spider alone....")
                time.sleep(6)
                print("As you start to walk away the spider ambushes you and impales you with its FANGS!!!!!!")
                complete = 0
                return complete
#turn right
if part2:
        print(" You turn right, away from the glowing object, and attempt to leave the cave.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("But something won't let you......")
        complete = 0
        return complete

# game loop

alive = true
while alive:
    complete = game()
    if complete == 1:
        alive = input("You managed to escape the cavern alive :) Would you like to play again, yes or no?")
        if alive == "yes" or alive == "Yes":
            alive

        else:
            break
    if complete == 0:
    alive = input("You have DIED, Would you like to play again, Yes or No?")
    if alive == "yes" or alive == "Yes":
            alive

            else:
                break
```

Comment: Clearly off-topic: a straight migration (though what they'll make of it I'm not sure)

Comment: @JosephWright: see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21351388#21351388 for what we made of it. :-) It's a code dump with multiple errors and no proper question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In the past I've asked the SO mods about migrations and got told off for that too! A similar question actually on-topic on the TeX site would probably get time to be improved and comments to help the OP solve their issue.

Comment: @JosephWright: not sure why the moderators would tell you off for asking about migrations. That's kinda the point of migration-by-moderator. This question goes against the specific OT reason for debugging questions; *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not a good reason for rejecting migration, in my opinion. Off topic on [so]? Perhaps (see the reason for closing). Off topic here? Certain.

Comment: @egreg: the migration was rejected because it was closed as off-topic over on Stack Overflow. Or are you talking about why it shouldn't have been migrated in the first place? The rule of thumb is to *not migrate crap*. If Stack Overflow did this to Tex, the Tex community would not be happy with having to clean up more mess that Stack Overflow could have just sent to the trashcan directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, but I'm a TeX.SX member, so I can't judge whether something is crap for [so]. I just know this question doesn't belong here, but it should belong to [so]. So I'd let the users there decide. Do you feel like deciding a TeX question is crap?

Comment: @egreg: there is no *migrate to Stack Overflow* migration option for members here, so you have to ask a moderator. The point being that community members here are not expected to know what is on-topic for SO, moderators get to make that call instead. So far, at least for all such moderator-led migrations on other sites, the moderators of the source and target site talk or at least have an understanding of what is on-topic on the other site. Otherwise they'll just close it as OT on the source site. That way you don't migrate crap, because that only creates more confusion for the poster.

Comment: @egreg: if over time community members ask for migrations to a specific site a lot, and statistics show that such migrations have been successful on the whole, then a site can be added to the 'vote to migrate' menu on a post.

Comment: @egreg: but if you are just going to migrate anything that looks remotely like Stack Overflow only because it contains code, then you are basically asking someone else to rake out the crap for you to find the quality posts, and that's not going to work. It is also not fair on the OP; they have their post shoved about unnecessarily, while it could just have been closed outright.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was talking in general. If I see a physics question on Math.SE, I vote for migration, without even thinking whether it's “crap” or not. I can say it's physics, but not judge about the quality, so I let experts decide. *This* is fair to the OP, who's directed to the suitable site for his/her questions.

Comment: @egreg: This is the reason that Programmers was taken of the Stack Overflow community migration list; people just generally migrated anything that looked like a programmers question without taking into account the question quality. Rather than migrate, if not sure, just close and inform the OP of the existence of the other site by *linking to the on-topic help page* of the other site.

Comment: @egreg: because if everyone did what you do, you double the work; questions being closed on one site *and* on the other rather than just in the one location.